# IAM approval in codepipeline when assuming role

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-roles

we have users logging in from our landing account to CI/CD account- usually with Admin or read-only roles.

We would like to use IAM groups in CI/CD account so that only the users in the specific groups can approve/reject the deployment (but we have NO users in the CI/CD account). We just have the required groups in place. However, since we do not create users in our CI/CD account, but only assume roles from our landing account, how do we use the IAM approval in the code pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups are only used with users so won't work in this context. You need to assign the permission in a policy on the relevant role:

For example:

Pipeline Arn: **arn:aws:codepipeline:eu-west-1:123456789:my-pipeline**

Pipeline Stage Name: **Prod**

Approval Action Name: **Approve-Prod**

```
- Action:
    - codepipeline:PutApprovalResult
Effect: Allow
Resource:
    - arn:aws:codepipeline:eu-west-1:123456789:my-pipeline/Prod/Approve-Prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `AWSCodePipelineApproverAccess` role to the group that can approve

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals.html

Comment: This is to me a confused question. A group is a collection of IAM users but you are not using users so you can not use groups.

Comment: A codepipeline does not have a resource policy so you would grant or deny actions to the users on the policy on the role they assume when logging into the account

Comment: Yes indeed, I misunderstood. So the role they assume need to have the above permission.

Comment: @RonanCunningham That would mean the policy allows approving/disapproving at all stages in the pipeline. I'd want to selectively allow some users to approve to production while others to approve to QA.

Comment: @SKhurana not quite - see answer